# Refresh the Navigation Menu of Community on Safari ipad

Tags: community, javascript-remoting, ipad

The issue is on iPad.

I have a tab in community, and on click we change the users language (call the controller using JS Remoting). On Success we are trying to go back to the page we were previously on.

ex: Page1 -> Page2 -> click language tab -------> change users language and go back to Page2, which is translated.

This functionality works fine in Chrome, but not in Safari.
I am using the below two lines on success

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.LangToggleController.updateUser}',
    function(result, event){
         if(event.status){
         if ( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && sforce && (!!sforce.one) ) {
           sforce.one.back(true);
           window.top.location.reload();
         }else{
            window.history.go(-1);
          }
        } else if (event.type === 'exception'){
           alert('Callout error: ' + event.message);
        } else {
        }
    }, 
    {escape: true}
    );
```

Comment: In what way is this not working? Is it not behaving as expected? Are you getting an error?

Comment: This is not working as expected in Safari . It works perfectly fine in chrome; It goes back to the page when the language toggle was clicked. the entire community reloads with the translated language and the navigation menu is also translated.

Comment: There is no error in Safari. It does not load the community with the translated language and "sforce.one.back(true);" takes it two pages back.